# How can I combine two variables into one in order to obtain an overall frequency pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem.

How can I combine two variables into one, in order to obtain an overall frequency pandas?

An example

```
Name, Count
Watch   2
Watch   3
Jacob   4
Jacob   3
Ashley  2
Ashley  2
```

The output I want is

```
Name    Count
Watch,    5
Jacob,    7
Ashley,   4
```

For my dataset which is around 700 rows, this is what I have been trying with groupby.

```
df.groupby(["NameOfProduct", "Number_Count"]).size().reset_index(name="Time")
```

It only give me the count of times, the variables appear in the dataset.

Hope you guys can help.

Thank you, and have a good evening :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is your are also grouping by `Count`. To get the correct groupby you would only want to groupby `Name`. For Example:

```
df.groupby(['Name']).sum()
```

This will take the sum of `Count` for every unique name in the DataFrame which should result in your requested output.

If you groupby ['Name', 'Count'] and use `size()` you will end up with a value of 1 for each group except for when `Name = Ashley` and `Count=2` (in this case the result would be 2). This is because `size` is going to return the size of each unique group.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That makes sense!